# How to debug when there are no logs?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

I'm working on compas-AR app. I have `UIImagePickerViewController` so I can have background from device camera. Inside `UIView overlay` I put all UI buttons/subviews. Every method has a `NSLog()` at the very beginning, so I can track in logs where app is going. Unfortunatelly I'm stuck. After downloading no data I use this `UIView nothingView` - which I declared and added with all subviews within `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`. Here comes the problem: `nothingView` is shown, but any interaction (rotating device, pressing my action `UIButtons` etc) is suspending app and all I got in logs is this:

> 2013-05-29 15:49:53.657 CloudReco copy[6246:707] GeoVC: targetsRequestDidFinishForContent 
>   2013-05-29 15:49:53.659 CloudReco copy[6246:707] GeoVC: there is no data from targets dictionary 
>   2013-05-29 15:49:53.662 CloudReco copy[6246:707] GeoVC: showNothing 
>   2013-05-29 15:49:53.664 CloudReco copy[6246:707] GeoVC: showNothing 2 
>   (gdb)

I did use anylizer, but it didn't point in any direction here. If I did only receive any method's `NSLog` I could try to follow, but with any trace I'm helpless.

Here is code snippet called when I send notification that nothing was found:

```
-(void)showNothing:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"GeoVC: showNothing");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"GeoVC: showNothing 2");
        loadingView.hidden = YES;
        closeButton.hidden = NO;
        startView.hidden = YES;
        gestrec.enabled = NO;
        nothingView.hidden = NO;
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    });
}
```

After that is ok, unless I rotate device or push any action button...
any help appreciated

**note:** I'm using iOS 5.1 and Xcode 4.2

**update:** that's all I got. Somehow `dealloc` is being called after all operations, despite I don't hide/exit/release any view - at least not "me"

> (gdb) bt
>   #0  0x37de2f78 in CoreLocationVersionNumber ()
>   #1  0x334b42bc in ?? ()

Comment: You need to set an exceptions breakpoint and run with exceptions enabled. Many posts on how to do that on SO. Then your app will show a stack trace when it crashes.

Comment: problem is it does not :/ even with exception breakpoints. Still looking for any clue why it stops working

Comment: If the console shows gdb as you show above, it's in the debugger. There has to be something showing in the stack trace, even if it's just main.

Comment: OK, I've found it - `dealloc` is being called after all of the stuff, but still have to find why is that

Answer (score 0):

Insure that you have an ivar or property keeping a strong reference to location objects, and never release them (ie nil them) in a delegate callback, rather dispatch a block to the main queue to release it. Ask me how I know this :-)